# Django: DateTime not good when saved on my database

Tags: django, python-2.7

It seems stupid but i have hard time since hours and hours about saving my dateTime on db. I'm pretty new in Python and it's not everyday that i'm manipulating datetime.
I have one hour of difference when i'm saving my value. So 18h is now 17h (sorry for my english)

My models is like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=245)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=750, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, editable=False)
    nb_participant = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, related_name='author')
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', editable=False, related_name='events')
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'event'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.created_at = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
            print self.created_at
        self.updated_at = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you see i have 4 fields with datetime. 2 are actually save automatically save when the model is created.

I resolved the probleme by using **timezone.localtime(timezone.now())** instead of **timezone.now()**. I find that there [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) at the bottom of the page. But they said to use timezone.now() in most case. So i don't know why i have this one hour difference.

I have two other fields that are send from my angular frontend to my API( using django rest framework)
I put a screenshot. The first object i send by angular.As you seen the date is well formatted.
The second object is the response from my API and i have lost one hour (so the GMT +1)

[image: object send and received]

Why ? I'm totally block so if someone has a solution, i'll be very happy :)

My settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In settings file try with USE_TZ=False, and use normal datetime.now().

Comment: Thxs and sorry to reply so late. It's seems that i have another with my mysql backend when i use False. I don't have time for now to investigate this point. But after some reading i decided to continu to use Timezone, it's seems that it's the better solution and the value is displayed well in template.